# How to fix 'call to a member functuin delete() on null' in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a form delete request, and every time I try to delete some content I get an error 'call to a member function delete on null'. I didn't used Laravel for a very long time, and I have forgotten how things work, and now I'm learning from beginning, following tutorial from Laracast. I compared the code and everything is good, but I get always some errors, and I cannot find a problem...

web.php

```
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');
```

ProjectsConroller

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
      $project = Project::find($id);

      $project->delete();

      return redirect('/projects');
    }
```

edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')


@section('content')

<h1>Edit Project</h1>

<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/projects/$project->id') }}" >

  {{ method_field('PATCH') }}

  {{ csrf_field() }}

  <div class="field">
    <label class="label" for="title">Title</label>

    <div class="control">
      <input type="text" class="input" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ $project->title }}">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label class="label" for="description">Description</label>

    <div class="control">
      <textarea name="description" class="textarea">{{ $project->description }}</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <button type="submit" class="button is-link">Update Project</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>

<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/projects/$project->id') }}">

  {{  method_field('DELETE') }}

  {{ csrf_field() }}

  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
       <button type="submit" class="button">Delete Project</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

@endsection()
```

Comment: Check the URL you're posting to. `{{ url('/projects/$project->id') }}` might not create the correct URL, try with `{{ url('/projects/'.$project->id) }}` (append the ID correctly)

Comment: Wow...thank's bro!! That really helped me a lot...I've spent hours trying to figure what's the problem

Comment: No problem! The answer below expands on the concept, so consider upvoting and accepting it. And don't forget the `dd()` function; if you has done a `dd($id)`, before calling `::find($id)`; you would have been able to debug that `$id` is not what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your code is wrong:
`<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/projects/$project->id') }}"`

It's passing $project->id as the ID instead of evaluating. You have 2 ways:

1. `<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/projects/'.$project->id) }}"`
2. `<form method="POST" action="{{ url("/projects/$project->id") }}"`

As an addition,
In your controller method, you might want to use `findOrFail()` instead of `find()` so it returns 404 when the model is not found. find() will return null if model is not found, and you're already trying to call `->delete()` on null.